# Angular js dynamic crawlers not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-crawlers

When I sharing my web application using meta tag static data showing

```html
 <!-- Dynamic data -->
 <meta name="author" content="{{ author.name }}" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="{{ title.description }}" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="{{ dynamictitle.name }}" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="{{ dynamictitle.image }}" />
  <!-- Static Data -->
    <meta name="author" content="authorname" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="A description of the post." />
  <meta property="og:title" content="The post title" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="images/img.jpg" />
```

but using dynamic data that time not working.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the new Meta Service from `@angular/platform-browser` ? This way you can update the meta tags on runtime: https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Meta

After adding the Meta Service you could use `this.metaservice.updateTag('og:title', dynamictitle.name)`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am using Angular js 1.x version, not Angular 2 and 4. Working in